# Convert byte content in ASCII to string

Tags: string, visual-studio, byte, c#-2.0, type-conversion

I'm working on  visual studio with c#, and I receive a message in a byte[], which containts let's say, byte[] = "6A" (representation of j in ASCII) and I would like to get the values of this byte[] into an string[] which contains the value as a string[1]="6A". But I don't know how to take the content of this byte to convert it to a string.

I have been checking several option but I couldn't find the right one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It feels strange that you want to convert a `byte[]` to a `string[]` (an array of `string`s) instead of a single `string` but...

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0x6a };
string[] strings = Array.ConvertAll(bytes, x => new string((char)x, 1));
```

Comment: It's because I want to read a header in which the first 2 bytes must be a defined value, the following 4, another specific value and so on.

Thanks for the answer

Comment: Just to be clear, casting a byte to a char (UTF-16 code unit) makes sense as long as the character encoding for the byte is ISO-8859-1 or a subset (ASCII might be the only one).